# Update multiple fields in mongo based on their existence

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to copy selected fields from collection 'a' to collection 'b'.
I would like to set multiple fields on b based on whether they exist in a.
i.e If the field dosen't exist in 'a; then I don't want to set it in 'b'.

This is what I'm trying

```
b.update_one(
              {"_id": xyz},
              {"$set": {"name": a['name'],
                        "lastname": a.get('lastname', None)}})
```

This gives me None is lastname doesn't exist.
I don't want lastname to be updated at all if there is not lastname in 'a'.
Is there any other alternative apart from using 2 set statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare the update definition beforehand. For example, suppose `a` has this value:

```
a = {
    'name': 'John'
}
```

Then define the update so that it only contains fields from `a` that you are interested in (and that are present in `a`):

```
update = {
    'name': a.get('name'),
    'lastname': a.get('lastname')
    ...
}
update = {k: v for k, v in update.items() if v is not None}
```

Now perform the update:

```
b.update_one(
    {"_id": xyz},
    {"$set": update}
)
```